# AJAX Post Request call showing “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ”

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to use the shorthand AJAX Post Request to *add a dog* to my API. However, it's not liking the fact that I have a ":" in my post request.

This is my post request function:

```
    //add(POST AJAX REQUEST) one dog to the api
    function addOneDog (myUrl) {
      $.post(myUrl, function(data) {
        dogBreed: "Hound Dog",
        dogName: "Freddy",
        dogAge: 5,
        dogColor: "White",
        dogPersonality: "Angry"
      })
    }
```

My Postman GET Request to my API:

```
    [
     {
       "dogBreed": "Border Collie",
       "dogName": "Bob",
       "dogAge": 2,
       "dogColor": "Brown",
       "dogPersonality": "Loyal",
       "id": 3,
       "createdAt": "2017-08-29T22:52:46.832Z",
       "updatedAt": "2017-08-29T22:52:46.832Z"
     }
    ]
```

I was following the example shown on the JQuery documentation:

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Any ideas? I think I am forgetting a syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Just some bad syntax, you're putting your POST data in the wrong spot - you currently have it in the callback function (which generates syntax errors):

```
$.post(myUrl, {
    dogBreed: "Hound Dog",
    dogName: "Freddy",
    dogAge: 5,
    dogColor: "White",
    dogPersonality: "Angry"
}, function(data) {
    //response is what data is
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/